# How to split a PowerShell command into multiple lines in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-groovy

How do I break this PoweShell command line over multiple lines in Jenkins?

```
bat """PowerShell.exe -Command \$items = (Get-Childitem).name; mkdir dir1//dir2; Move-Item \$items -Destination dir1/dir2"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a '^' at the break point. Here's a working example where I assign the IP of a running Docker container to a variable...

```
for /F %%x in ('docker inspect -f "{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" oracle-xe')^
do set ip=%%x
```